# How to use PHP memcached for session storage with Auto Scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, php.ini, autoscaling, php-memcached

I already have `memcached` installed in my servers and I've modified the default `php.ini` to:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

I'm using Amazon EC2 instances (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) with Auto Scaling and Load Balancer, but I've a big question in my mind about the `PHP memcached`. First, explaining my problem: I've stored `sessions` in my `Server A` and I've another `Server B` also running. But, when I stop `Server A` (that I'm connected with `sessions`), the Load Balancer redirects me to `Server B` and it looks like the `sessions` are lost, because I'm disconnected of my website and he asks me to sign in again.

And I read this excerpt for use memcached for session storage on multiple servers (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884905/using-memcache-as-a-session-store/9526394#9526394)):

> In your php.ini you should set session.save_path to the list of
>   memcached servers, for example server1:11211, server2:11211.

But how can I say in who will be `server1:11211` and `server2:11211` being that I am using Auto Scaling and I may have "n" servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your memcached server(s) should be outside of your ASG. As you know, state cannot be stored in ASG instances. So, either use AWS's Elasticache service or run your own memcached server, then point your ASG instances there.